# CSS Toggle Switch(Checkbox) value always on/checked

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, uiswitch

I just styled the `checkbox` as `toggle switch` in CSS, It works fine. However, the value of input seems to not change on `onchange` event and shows always `on`.

**JS code:**

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="console.log(this.value);">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's visual behaviour is perfect, but not internal. What is the reason that caused the issue? any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working example:  https://jsfiddle.net/mg7sLa21/

Use the checked property to determine the checkbox state, then assign a value based on that state.

JS

```
document.getElementById('checkbox1').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  this.checkboxValue = e.target.checked ? 'on' : 'off';
  console.log(this.checkboxValue)
})
```

HTML

```
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <center>
      <label class="switch">
        <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </center>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line it's browser specific .
Checkbox has **checked** property by which you can distinguish, it's checked or not (on/off)/(true/false).
if you want to print somthing else instead of 'ON' you add **value='true'** **value='passed value'** attribute, which will print always true or passed value.

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="console.log(this.checked)">
```